# Configure the routers cakephp to make unlimited/optional parameters

Tags: cakephp, parameters, routes

I have a system to allow the visitor browse products by listing, sorting and filtering it.

I want my url look like this `"/category/smartphones/samsung/android/.../"` when the visitors filters by selection "brand", "operting system type", "cpu", ... so every things they're filtering, url will change like :

```
filter by brand : /category/smartphones/samsung/
by os type : /category/smartphones/android/
by brand and os type : /category/smartphones/samsung/android/
...
```

also, visitors can sort while they're filtering or they can filter while they're sorting. so the url can be more like `"/category/smartphones/samsung/android/sort:created/direction:desc/"`

I don't know cakephp can do something like that or not because I'm beginner in this framework. or any solution with something like that?

I just done with sorting configuration in router. but I don't know how to start with something like that (filters is unlimited parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite easy, and you don't even need an entry in the routes file if you're happy with Cake's default routing method.  :-)

This is what I did...

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    function test() {
        debug($this->params['named']);
        debug($this->params['pass']);
    }
}
```

Then I called... `http://localhost/pages/test/x/y/z/something:x/else:y/1/2/3`

It output this...

```
array(
    'something' => 'x',
    'else' => 'y'
)

array(
    (int) 0 => 'x',
    (int) 1 => 'y',
    (int) 2 => 'z',
    (int) 3 => '1',
    (int) 4 => '2',
    (int) 5 => '3'
)
```

So you simply use `$this->params['named']` and `$this->params['pass']` to get the terms you need.  Hope that helps!